# Does Bluetooth Low Energy supports web?

Tags: android, react-native, web, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am new at multiple OS apps. I want to build a Bluetooth low energy based application using react native or flutter. To make Bluetooth scan and set connections;

->React Native has react-native-ble-plx https://dotintent.github.io/react-native-ble-plx/ package,

->Flutter has quick_blue https://pub.dev/packages/quick_blue package and flutter_blue https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_blue packages.

These packages are only packages that I found as a result of my researches. But the problem is I cannot find any information about if one of the packages that I indicate above supports IOS, Android and web applications at the same time.

Can someone who knows about multi platform and multiple OS applications help me about to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use BLE from a browser using the [Web Bluetooth API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Bluetooth_API). Take a look at [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Bluetooth_API#browser_compatibility) table for information about specific browser support. You can find some examples for Chrome [here](https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/web-bluetooth/).

That said, the flutter BLE libraries you posted only support iOS/Android but not web. The only library I found that supports Web Bluetooth is [flutter_web_bluetooth](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_web_bluetooth) but it does not support iOS or Android.

I don't know of any library that supports all three.

Comment: Thank you, but I think Web Bluetooth API  does not support Android apps and Apple aps.

Comment: Web Bluetooth supports some mobile browser, but as I said: I don't know of any library that supports Android, iOS and web in one